# KeyError: 'logits'

Tags: huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, huggingface-tokenizers

I am facing an issue while loading huggingface model which I downloaded to local

```
saved_model_directory = "model-base"

model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(saved_model_directory, local_files_only=True)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(saved_model_directory, local_files_only=True)

pipe = pipeline("ner", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, aggregation_strategy="simple")

print(pipe("My name is Clara and I live in Berkeley, California."))
```

I get the following KeyError Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\model_download.py", line 73, in <module>
    print(pipe("My name is Clara and I live in Berkeley, California."))
  File "C:\Users\user1\env\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\token_classification.py", line 249, in __call__
    return super().__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\env\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\base.py", line 1112, in __call__
    return next(
  File "C:\Users\user1\env\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\pt_utils.py", line 124, in __next__
    item = next(self.iterator)
  File "C:\Users\user1\env\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\pt_utils.py", line 266, in __next__
    processed = self.infer(next(self.iterator), **self.params)
  File "C:\Users\user1\env\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\base.py", line 1026, in forward
    model_outputs = self._forward(model_inputs, **forward_params)
  File "C:\Users\user1\env\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\token_classification.py", line 287, in _forward
    logits = output["logits"] if isinstance(output, dict) else output[0]
  File "C:\Users\user1\env\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\generic.py", line 318, in __getitem__
    return inner_dict[k]
KeyError: 'logits'
```

I am expecting the NER output from this model